# SQL database search

Tags: sql, sql-server, nlp

I have a table that contains about 1 million rows.

The rows looks like this:

[image: example]

EngPos field type = NVARCHAR(max)

I need some sort of a query that will find a row.

**Entry format:** (like EngPos field)

```
...+...+...+...+...
```

**This is my code:**

```
    DECLARE @Search varchar(255),@var1 int,@var2 int,@var3 int
    SET @Search='LS+VB+TO+NN+IN+NN'+'+'

    SELECT 
       EngPos
        FROM MyDB         

        WHERE EngPos Like @Search
        SELECT @var1=@@Rowcount

    if(@var1=0)
    begin

    SELECT 
       EngPos
        FROM MyDB         

        WHERE EngPos Like @Search+'%' 
        SELECT @var2=@@Rowcount

    end

    if(@var2=0)
    begin

    SELECT 
       EngPos
        FROM MyDB         

        WHERE EngPos Like '%'+@Search 
        SELECT @var3=@@Rowcount

    end

    if (@var3=0)
    begin

    SELECT 
       EngPos
        FROM MyDB         

        WHERE EngPos Like '%'+@Search+'%' 

    end
```

As you can see in this code>>> input=**"LS+VB+TO+NN+IN+NN"**

For this input my query returns nothing.

However, if my input was **"VB+TO+NN+IN+NN"** >>> it finds 2 rows.

I need a query that can find a match, even if the row(s) does not contain all of my input string characters.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  How many records is this likely to hold?  What sort of response time are you after?

Comment: Is there a question here? Your life would be a lot easier if you normalized your data instead of cramming all these values into a single column.

Comment: Although your data is not well normalized have you simply tried a '%LIKE%' query?  I.e. Where EngPos like '%...+...+...+...+...%'

Comment: Use the create a fulltext on the table and then search on it. Sample: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/ 
MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by a subset of other records?

Comment: @BrianAtkins i have edited the question and explained more of my problem.

Comment: @TabAlleman i have edited the question and explained more of my problem.

Comment: @JonM i have edited the question and explained more of my problem.

Comment: Chelsea-fc, It's good you added to the description, but I'm not sure it has made life any easier.  Some things are not that obvious such as why the query returns nothing.  Can you reproduce the problem with a tiny table (20 rows) and then post those rows, together with an example of the kinds of queries you want to submit (and what you believe should and shouldn't match)? Your description is still not that clear.

Comment: What is your rule for what should return a match?   If your input was "TO+NN" should it return every row that has EITHER "TO" or "NN" even if it doesn't have the other?

Comment: @TabAlleman the answer for your question is yes. for example>>> if input="VB+TO+NN+IN+NN" and in DB this string does n't exist exactly but there is a record such as "TO+NN+IN" in DB,i need a query that can return this record.

Comment: You're going to need to use a split function on your input string then, and JOIN the results of the function to the table.